# Открыть один фрагмент с recyclerview.adapter в другом фрагменте с recyclerview.adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview.adapter

**MainAcitivy**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MovieListAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            add(R.id.flMain, FragmentMovieList())
            commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onItemClick() {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.flMain, FragmentMoviesDetails())
            addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
        }
     }
}
```

**FirstAdapter**

```
class MovieListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var list = listOf<Movie>()
    private var itemclick: ItemClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_holder_movie,parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val movie = list[position]
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            holder.avatar?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.avatar))
            holder.years?.text = movie.years
            holder.heart?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.heart_avatar))
            holder.genre?.text = movie.genre
            holder.star1?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.star1))
            holder.star2?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.star2))
            holder.star3?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.star3))
            holder.star4?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.star4))
            holder.star5?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(movie.star5))
            holder.review?.text = movie.reviews
            holder.name?.text = movie.name
            holder.time?.text = movie.time
            holder.rvActor?.apply { setOnClickListener{
                itemclick?.onItemClick()
            } }
        }
    }

    fun bindActors(newMovie: List<Movie>) {
        list = newMovie
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val avatar: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivMain)
        val years: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvYears)
        val heart: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivHeart)
        val genre: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvGenre)
        val star1: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStar1)
        val star2: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStar2)
        val star3: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStar3)
        val star4: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStar4)
        val star5: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStar5)
        val review: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReviews)
        val name: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
        val time: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime)
        val rvActor: RecyclerView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvActors)

    }
    interface ItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick()
    }
}
```

**SecondAdapter**

```
class MovieDetailAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieDetailAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var listDetail = listOf<MovieDetail>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_holder_actor, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieDetailAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val detail = listDetail[position]
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            holder.imageDetail?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.imageDetail))
            holder.detailName?.text = detail.detailName
            holder.detailAge?.text = detail.detailAge
            holder.tag?.text = detail.tag
            holder.detailStar1?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.detailStar1))
            holder.detailStar2?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.detailStar2))
            holder.detailStar3?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.detailStar3))
            holder.detailStar4?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.detailStar4))
            holder.detailStar5?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.detailStar5))
            holder.detailReviews?.text = detail.detailReviews
            holder.detailStory?.text = detail.story.toString()
            holder.actor1?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.actor1))
            holder.actor2?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.actor2))
            holder.actor3?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.actor3))
            holder.actor4?.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.context.getDrawable(detail.actor4))
            holder.nameActor1?.text = detail.nameActor1
            holder.nameActor2?.text = detail.nameActor2
            holder.nameActor3?.text = detail.nameActor3
            holder.nameActor4?.text = detail.nameActor4
        }
    }

    fun bindActorsDetail(newDetail: List<MovieDetail>) {
        listDetail = newDetail
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listDetail.size

    class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val imageDetail: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageDetail)
        val detailName: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailName)
        val detailAge: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yearsDetail)
        val tag: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag)
        val detailStar1: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStar1)
        val detailStar2: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStar2)
        val detailStar3: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStar3)
        val detailStar4: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStar4)
        val detailStar5: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStar5)
        val detailReviews: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailReviews)
        val detailStory: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailStory)
        val actor1: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDetail1)
        val actor2: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDetail2)
        val actor3: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDetail3)
        val actor4: ImageView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDetail4)
        val nameActor1: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetail1)
        val nameActor2: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetail2)
        val nameActor3: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetail3)
        val nameActor4: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetail4)

    }
}
```

**FirstFragmnet**

```
class FragmentMovieList : Fragment() {

    private var recycler: RecyclerView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_list, container, false)

        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        recycler =  view.findViewById(R.id.rvActors)
        recycler?.adapter = MovieListAdapter()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        updateData()
        super.onStart()
    }

    private fun updateData() {
        (recycler?.adapter as? MovieListAdapter)?.apply {
            bindActors(MovieData().getMovie())
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondFragment**

```
class FragmentMoviesDetails : Fragment() {

    private var recyclerDetail: RecyclerView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies_details, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        recyclerDetail =  view.findViewById(R.id.rvDetail)
        recyclerDetail?.adapter = MovieDetailAdapter()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        updateData()
        super.onStart()
    }

    private fun updateData() {
        (recyclerDetail?.adapter as? MovieDetailAdapter)?.apply {
            bindActorsDetail(DetailData().getDetail())
        }
    }
}
```

Я использую список с некоторыми данными для первого и второго адаптера.
Я проделал некоторые действия, чтобы при нажатии на иконку в первом фрагменте я переходил ко второму фрагменту, но ничего не появлялось.
Без recyclerview.adapter переходы между фрагментами происходили

Comment: Кажется, вы забыли переменную проинициализировать: `private var itemclick: ItemClickListener? = null`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб извините я новичок в этот деле, в MainActivity я создал метод для перехода на следующий фрагмент, а в адаптере уже через созданный интерфейс вызываю этот метод, как именно я должен проинициализировать указанную вами переменную. (Извините если глупый вопрос)

Comment: Вроде как вам надо, например, реализовать MovieListAdapter.ItemClickListener в FragmentMovieList, сделать var itemclick: ItemClickListener публичной и инициализировать её в FragmentMovieList примерно так (после инициализации адаптера):  (recycler?.adapter as? MovieListAdapter).itemclick = this

Comment: @ЮрийСПб извините не совсем понял что вы имели ввиду, в классе FragmnetMovieList, я повторно проинициализировал (public var itemclick: MovieListAdapter.ItemClickListener? = null),потом в методе FragmnetMovieList onViewCreated после инициализации адаптера я прописал эту строку (recycler?.adapter as? MovieListAdapter).itemclick = this, но после этого класс просит имплиментировать метод из MainActivity onItemClick().

Comment: Объявлять переменную во фрагменте - необязательно. Вам надо или перенести метод onItemClick во фрагмент перенеся также и `: MovieListAdapter.ItemClickListener` во фрагмент, убрав это из MainActivity или вызвать метод активити, скастовав `Activity` фрагмента к MainActivity.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял вы имели ввиду что то на подобии этого:              class FragmentMovieList : Fragment(), MovieListAdapter.ItemClickListener {   
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        recycler = view.findViewById(R.id.rvActors)
        (recycler?.adapter as? MovieListAdapter)?.itemclick = this
        recycler?.adapter = MovieListAdapter() }

Comment: @ЮрийСПб override fun onItemClick() {
        activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.apply {
            replace(R.id.flMain, FragmentMoviesDetails(), null)
            addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
        }

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это изменения которые я внёс, плюс еще убрал метод из MainActivity, к сожалению программа запускается но все ещё нет перехода между фрагментами

Comment: В показанном вами коде всё ещё нет инициализации слушателя клика в адаптере. Точнее оно есть, но его надо поменять местами с созданием адаптера. Вы сначала слушатель пытаетесь в несуществующий адаптер поставить и только потом создаёте адаптер

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо вам огромное, извините что так сильно тупил, всё получилось, хорошего вам дня и всех благ!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста) Успехов в кодинге)